# My if statement is not working as expected

Tags: php, database, if-statement, foreach, echo

This code are duplicating the meta tags, according with how many data i have on the column `entry_type`, independently if the `entry_type` is `post` or `pagina` of the page that i'm on. And it's printing out the `meta` tags from both `if` and `else`.

```
$mt = $conn->query("SELECT entry_type FROM bn_publicacao")->fetchAll();

foreach ($mt as $FB) {

    if ($FB['entry_type'] == 'pagina'){ 
        echo '<meta property="og:type" content="website">';
    } else{
        echo '<meta property="og:type" content="article">';
        echo '<meta property="article:author" content="">';
        echo '<meta property="article:publisher" content="">';
        echo '<meta property="article:published_time" content="">';
        echo '<meta property="article:modified_time" content="">';
    }

 }
```

**Edit:** I solved the problem with the duplicates

```
$mt = $conn->query("SELECT entry_type FROM bn_publicacao WHERE entry_type IS NOT NULL GROUP BY entry_type")->fetchAll();

foreach ($mt as $FB) {

    if ($FB['entry_type'] == 'pagina'){ 
        echo '<meta property="og:type" content="website">';
    } else{
        echo '<meta property="og:type" content="article">';
        echo '<meta property="article:author" content="">';
        echo '<meta property="article:publisher" content="">';
        echo '<meta property="article:published_time" content="">';
        echo '<meta property="article:modified_time" content="">';
    }

 }
```

But i still have the problem that both `if` and `else` is printing out at same time.

Results from the `print_r`:

```
$mt = $conn->query("SELECT entry_type FROM bn_publicacao WHERE entry_type IS NOT NULL GROUP BY entry_type")->fetchAll();

foreach ($mt as $FB) {
print_r($mt); //Result 1

    if ($FB['entry_type'] == 'pagina'){
    print_r($mt); //Result 2

        //code posted on the question

    } else{    
      print_r($mt); //Result 3

        //code posted on the question

    }

}
```

- **Result 1:**

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [entry_type] => pagina [0] => pagina ) [1] => Array ( [entry_type] => post [0] => post ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [entry_type] => pagina [0] => pagina ) [1] => Array ( [entry_type] => post [0] => post ) )

- **Result 2:**

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [entry_type] => pagina [0] => pagina ) [1] => Array ( [entry_type] => post [0] => post ) )

- **Result 3:**

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [entry_type] => pagina [0] => pagina ) [1] => Array ( [entry_type] => post [0] => post ) )

What's wrong on my code? And how can i solve it?

Comment: Verify what `fetchColumn()` returns

Comment: @Akintunde-Rotimi you meant `var_dump($mtFB);`? the result is NULL

Comment: if var_dump($mtFB); is null then perhaps your query is not returning any data and render else part all the time?

Comment: @SameerJain Please check my question again, i edited.

Comment: @user236945896 your code is doing exactly what is told to do, so you will see a lot of duplicates meta tags. What you need is to make the array unique, may be query it like "SELECT DISTINCT entry_type FROM bn_publicacao"

Comment: @SameerJain With the `"SELECT DISTINCT entry_type FROM bn_publicacao"` I don't get so many duplicates, but it duplicate the `meta` tag once. I solved the problem with the duplicates with the code that i posted on the  Question, but both `if` and `else` are still printing out all meta tags, together. Plese check my Edit, on the Question.

Comment: @user236945896 in that case query must only return what entry_type needed, right now you are returning both entry_type which in turn will print both condition one for pagina and one for post. hope this helps

Comment: @SameerJain Sorry but i'm new, i did not understood much what you was trying to say, how can i solve it?

Comment: @user236945896 I think first you need to find out which entry_type is required for that page and based on that you need to change your query to either return pagina or post

Comment: @SameerJain How would be that query? The page is configured with `pagina` or `post` on my DB correctly, so i don't know why it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

`fetchColumn` returns only one result, [fetchColumn](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php). You can use [fetchAll](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) which returns all results as array.

You need to loop through the results as it will be an array. Code below:

```
$mtFBs = $conn->query("SELECT entry_type FROM bn_publicacao")->fetchAll();
foreach ($mtFbs as $mtFb) {
   if ($mtFB['entry_type'] == 'pagina'){ 
     echo '<meta property="og:type" content="website">';
   } else{
      echo '<meta property="og:type" content="article">';
      echo '<meta property="article:author" content="">';
      echo '<meta property="article:publisher" content="">';
      echo '<meta property="article:published_time" content="">';
      echo '<meta property="article:modified_time" content="">';
   }
 }
```

Comment: so, *what* should they use instead? You're not giving them much to go on here, especially them being new at this. What you have now in the answer, is fit as a comment, IMHO.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner well said. Answer improved with solution.

Comment: Thank you :-) that helps them.

Comment: @Jacob Please check my question again, i made some changes on my code according with your answear. and i edited my question, adding more information.

Comment: @user236945896 I suggest you use this query `SELECT DISTINCT(entry_type) as entry_type FROM bn_publicacao WHERE entry_type IS NOT NULL;`  Then in your if and else statement, you should `print_r($FB)`.

Comment: @Jacob `print_r($FB)` on the `if` = `Array ( [entry_type] => pagina [0] => pagina )` and `print_r($FB)` on the `else` = `Array ( [entry_type] => post [0] => post )` why it's not working? It still print out `if` and `else` at same time.

Comment: @user236945896 you might have to check your code again and be 100% sure you are not inputing the same details in both conditions. As seen from the response you sent, if and else works as it should as If has `pagina` while else has `post`. The issue with your code isn't if/else again. Let me know if i can help